# DS-series, DSv2-series, FS-series VM

Tags: azure

Premium disk page says this type of disk are supported only on  DS-series, DSv2-series, FS-series VM .
  However I cannot find any such series VMs in Azure Compute pricing page or in Azure price calculator . Are these type of VMs still available ? Or the premium disk page is outdated ?

Thanks

Comment: updated answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>No, the page isn't outdated, the page is correct. But the calculator page is bugged (probably). I don't see those types either. Should be there.</strike>

Wow, it never came to my attention that prices for x and xS machines are the same (only the storage differs and storage is billed separately). So I guess that the calculator us fine. Deceptive, thou.

So to calculate price for DS2_v2 use D2_v2 machine. It has the same price.

Comment: as you say calculator is deceptive.. also even though it is the same price , they mention those instance types and specify same price .